# naming scheme for lightweight objects

Tags: naming-conventions

I need to come up with a naming scheme for the situation where some objects will exist in two versions.  Let's say server side has File and Directory objects and it passes a lightweight version of these to the client side.  The names LightweightFile and LightweightDirectory are obviously too long and clunky.  What's a good word to use instead of lightweight here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have been using "Data Transfer Objects" shortened to DTO.  It's a little wordy and requires the abbreviation though (which is why I found this question).

Comment: nice, apparently DTO is the actual term for what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Lightweight client-side representations of server-side objects are often called `Stub` or `Proxy`.

Comment: I think Stub is mostly something generated/dumb that doesn't do anything.  Proxy also assumes some action.  And I'm talking about value objects used for data passing, no behavior associated with them.

Comment: @MK: You didn't say anything about value objects in your question. That completely changes the terminology. Oh, "Stub" is standard client-server terminology for an active client object that talks to the server.